# Is there an implementation of _rational_ interval arithmetic in Python?

Tags: python, intervals, cpython, infinity, rational-numbers

Is there an implementation of *rational* interval arithmetic in Python?  [This](http://pyinterval.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html/index.html) uses floats, not rationals.

If not, is there any implementation of rationals in Python that includes ±∞ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Sympy](http://code.google.com/p/sympy/) has [intervals](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#interval), rational numbers, and infinity. The Interval class is a subclass of the [Set](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#set) class.

```
# oo is the symbol for infinity
from sympy import Interval, oo, Rational

i1 = Interval(10, 15)
i2 = Interval(0, oo)
i3 = Interval(-5, -1)
# adding intervals
i4 = i1 + i3
i5 = i1 + i2
# interval with open end
i6 = Interval(Rational(1, 2), Rational(45, 3), left_open=True)

print 11 in i1 # True
print -1 in i1 # False
print 0 in i4 # False
print Rational(3, 2) in i6 # True
print oo in i2 # False
print i2.sup # oo (infinity)
print Rational(1, 2) in i6 # False
print i6.inf # 1/2
```

Answer (score 0):

PyInterval now has rational interval arithmetic in Python feature.

[From PyInterval Docs](http://pyinterval.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide.html):

> The interval package can be loaded into the Python interpreter with the statement which injects in the current namespace the interval class, a constant representing the mathematical infinity, and a module providing interval transcendental functions.

```
from interval import interval, inf, imath

interval[0, 2] * interval[4, inf]
interval([-inf, inf])
```